# No Segmentation fault why? returned function value used as parameter

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault

Can the code below cause segmentation fault?

```
struct Dim {
  int x, y, z;
};

Dim set_dim(int a) {
 Dim l;
 l.x=a;
 l.y=a;
 l.z=a;
 return l;
}

int sum(const Dim &m) {
  int s=m.x+m.y;
  return s;
}

main() {
  cout<<sum(set_dim(5))<<endl;
}
```

I think it can because a reference is taken of a local variable 'l' in set_dim, in other word a reference to variable now out of scope. But never the less it works

Comment: What reference?  You're just returning a structure by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well-defined. `set_dim` returns by value, so its returned object is a temporary copy of the local variable `l`. This temporary is then bound to the `const` reference argument of `sum`. This affects the lifetime of the temporary object:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

So the lifetime of the temporary object is the full-expression `cout<<sum(set_dim(5))<<endl;`. It still exists while `sum` is executing.

Answer (score 3):

A reference of `l` is never taken (*not directly may be due to return value optimizations indirectly but you don't have to worry about that*).

- `set_dim` returns a **copy of `l`**. A temporary copy which will be
  passed to `sum`.
- `sum` can accept a temporary because it takes a const reference and
  everything worked out just fine and they all lived happily until
  `sum` returned.

Answer (score 1):

`set_dim` does not return a reference but a copy of l, so I don't think there is any chance of seg fault.